# Xcode 4.3 : Clang LLVM 1.0 Error

Tags: xcode, sdl, llvm, clang

I would like to use SDL in a project, so I create a Cocoa Project and I add all Framework needed, but XCode tells me this :

```
ProcessPCH /Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/projetCS2-Prefix-auneaovyjutgotajcmkllwxdblci/projetCS2-Prefix.pch.pth projetCS2/projetCS2-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/aurelien/Documents/Programmation/projetC-S2/projetCS2
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -I/Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/projetCS2.build/Debug/projetCS2.build/projetCS2.hmap -I/Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Headers -I/Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/projetCS2.build/Debug/projetCS2.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/projetCS2.build/Debug/projetCS2.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks --serialize-diagnostics /Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/projetCS2-Prefix-auneaovyjutgotajcmkllwxdblci/projetCS2-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/aurelien/Documents/Programmation/projetC-S2/projetCS2/projetCS2/projetCS2-Prefix.pch -o /Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/projetCS2-Prefix-auneaovyjutgotajcmkllwxdblci/projetCS2-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/aurelien/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projetCS2-gdnozsjskcozmxcvmlmmpsmmkcvk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/projetCS2-Prefix-auneaovyjutgotajcmkllwxdblci/projetCS2-Prefix.pch.d

error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you are using ARC (automatic reference counting) on your project, and that it's not supported using the fragile ABI (simulator).

You are surely building your app for 32-bits.
ARC is 64-bits only.

Try to update your projects settings, and build for 64-bits instead of 32 or universal.